# How to measure subprocess memory usage?

Tags: python, memory, subprocess

I want to run a few subprocesses in Python and get the amount of memory usage of these processes. I need only memory usage of the child processes and not the Python program.

```py
import subprocess

out = subprocess.check_output([...], shell=True)

// Get somehow the usage
```

Could you please describe me if there's a way to get it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `psutil` library which is cross platform so you can use it in many OS

```
import psutil,subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen([...])

process = psutil.Process(proc.pid)
mem_info=process.memory_info()
```

Here the return values explanation from the `psutil` doc:

> `memory_info()` :
>
> Return a named tuple with variable fields depending on the platform
> representing memory information about the process. The “portable”
> fields available on all plaforms are rss and vms. **All numbers are**
> **expressed in bytes**.

rss:

> aka “Resident Set Size”, this is the non-swapped physical memory
> a process has used. On UNIX it matches “top“‘s RES column). On Windows
> this is an alias for wset field and it matches “Mem Usage” column of
> taskmgr.exe.

vms:

> aka “Virtual Memory Size”, this is the total amount of virtual memory used by the process. On UNIX it matches “top“‘s VIRT
> column. On Windows this is an alias for pagefile field and it matches
> “Mem Usage” “VM Size” column of taskmgr.exe.

shared:

> (Linux) memory  that could be potentially shared with other processes. This matches
> “top“‘s SHR column).

text (Linux, BSD):

> aka TRS (text resident set)  the amount of memory devoted to executable code. This matches “top“‘s
> CODE column).

data

> (Linux, BSD): aka DRS (data resident set) the  amount of physical memory devoted to other than executable code. It
> matches “top“‘s DATA column).

lib (Linux):

> the memory used by shared libraries.

dirty (Linux):

> the number of dirty pages. pfaults (macOS):  number of page faults. pageins (macOS): number of actual pageins.